# Understanding how to initialize the ith element of an array parameter with the i+1th number of a harmonic series?

Tags: c++

This is my first C++ class and I'm not really sure how to proceed in my homework, as understanding arrays has been fairly difficult for me. I've successfully completed the 1st task, but got stuck understanding the 2nd and don't really know how to start it.

The tasks are:

1. Define a function named **harmonicNum()** that finds and returns the **n**th harmonic number using an iteration statement where **n** is a positive int-typed argument provided by the caller.
2. Given a valid array index **i**, define a function named **fillHarmonic()** that iteratively calls harmonicNum() to initialize the **i**th element of an array parameter wit the **i+1**th number of the harmonic series. I must define this function to work on a one-dimensional array of **any** size.

This is the code that I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

double harmonicNum(int n);
int n;

int main()
{
    do
    {
        cout << "Please input a positive integer: " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    } while (n < 0);

    cout << harmonicNum(n) << endl;
    return 0;
}

double harmonicNum(n)
{
    double harmonic = 0.00
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        harmonic = harmonic + 1.00 / i;
    }
    return harmonic;
}
```

Comment: Don't post code as images, copy-paste it in your question.

Comment: Can you tell us what you do and don't understand about arrays? That way we can help you understand what's needed to do the second task.

Comment: javascript is camelCase naming convention. C++ is PascalCase naming convention.

Comment: @HermanVanDerBlom: Neither JavaScript nor C++ has any mandated rules for cases in names, nor is any naming convention universally accepted for either.

Comment: @Eric, I know, C++ often used the underscore to for variables. In C# its mandated and it should be in C++, but to much legacy already exists they can not do that anymore. But when you start with a clean slade I think its better :-)

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?
Method definition:

```
void fillHarmonic(double &i_elem, int i){
    i_elem = harmonicNum(i+1); 
}
```

Call without error checking:

```
double arr [5];
//TODO init values
for(int i = 0; i < (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(double)); i++ ){
    fillHarmonic(arr[i], i);
}
```

Comment: @Yunnosch Don't get it what's wrong here due to the link. Array is here local variable inside main() or other method. Reference will be always valid in this case.

Comment: You are the second one referring to a link while addressing me. I do not see a link. Can you help me find it?

Comment: @Yunnosch Ok, now I know how it was meant. I forgot to add index as parameter. If  your second comment is still actual after my edit: The fillHarmonic should accept 1-D any size array, so arr size can be 5 or 6, 666 and the function should work.

Comment: Using a fixed size c-style array is unlikely to match the "I must define this function to work on a one-dimensional array of any size.". Of course the shown code does work with any size of a fixed size array (though the idiom uses `sizeof(arr[0])`. But having a fixed size array is an assumption which conflicts. Admittedly it is my interpretation, but "it works for any size, as long as that size is a constant at compile time" seems unlikely to be accepted as reasoning for "works with any size" requirement. Which I read as "works with any runtime-determined size" (e.g. based on user input).

Comment: @Ales100 please indent your code

Comment: @Yunnosch You are of course right. I expected any sized double array because the function harmonicNum() returns double.

Comment: The function should not return anything just fill the array which by the way should be dynamically allocated and thus you should have just used std::vector (which for many reasons is a better choice then "C" style arrays anyway).